# Ошибка при создании массива generics

Tags: java, массивы, generics

Предположим, есть такой код:

```
List<Integer>[] lists = new ArrayList<Integer>[10];
```

Компилятор не пропустит такого объявления. Почему?

P.S. Я знаю, что создавать подобный массив в реальном коде не стоит (лучше использовать коллекции) и знаю способы как обойти эту ошибку.

Comment: P.S. я знаю, что создавать подобный массив в реальном коде не стоит (лучше использовать коллекции) и знаю способы как обойти эту ошибку

Answer (score 6):

В [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/fineprint.html) сказано, что создание массивов из объектов параметризованного типа запрещено для избежания подобной ситуации:

```
//Предположим, что такое объявление было бы возможно
List<String>[] lsa = new List<String>[10];
Object o = lsa;
Object[] oa = (Object[])o;
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
li.add(new Integer(3));
//присвоение не вызывает ошибок
oa[1] = li;
//Ошибка в run-time: ClassCastException.
String s = lsa[1].get(0);
```

В этой ситуации код бы скомпилировался, но "сломался" при запуске.

Однако допускается использование wildcard `<?>` с явным приведением к `String` в последней строке:

```
List<?>[] lsa = new List<?>[10];
Object o = lsa;
Object[] oa = (Object[])o;
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
li.add(new Integer(3));
//Корректно
oa[1] = li;
//Ошибка в run-time, но приведение было явным
String s = (String)lsa[1].get(0);
```

Раз приведение было явным, то это говорит о том, что, во-первых, здесь может возникнуть `ClassCastException`, а во-вторых, что это уже забота программиста - приведение к корректному типу.

---

Да, в первой строке можно написать так:

```
List<String>[] lsa = new List[10];
```

И тогда код скомпилируется и "свалится" с `ClassCastException` в последней строке. Однако тут нужно учитывать, что в этой записи в левой части используется параметризованный тип, а в правой - [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). Такая запись не является рекомендуемой к использованию (кроме ситуаций, когда это действительно необходимо). В частности, потому что допускает некорректную ситуацию:

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1);
List<String>[] lsa = new List[] { ints };
String s = lsa[0].get(0);
```

Код скомпилируется и, как это было уже не раз в ответе, приведёт к `ClassCastException` в последней строке.

Comment: Первый пример не понял
 `List<String>[] lsa = new ArrayList[10];`
Если мы объявим лист таким образом компилятор точно также не выдаст ошибку и будет exception в runtime

Comment: @Evgenb безусловно. Однако использование `List<String> = new ArrayList()` не рекомендуется (кроме ситуаций, когда без этого никак). Поэтому такой вариант в документации не рассматривается.

Comment: Ок `ArrayList<String>[] lsa = new ArrayList[10];` такой вариант выдаст только uncheked assigment (то есть компилятор, ошибку не выдаст) и соостветвенно нам также будет выдана ошибка в runtime. Почему тогда компилятор не дается записать так`List<String>[] lsa = new List<String>[10];`, ведь должны быть какая-то объективаня причина

Comment: @Evgenb причина указана в ответе и в документации (а именно для избежания ситуации, смоделированной в первом примере). Ваш вариант `ArrayList<String>[] lsa = new ArrayList[10]` ничем в плане проблемы не отличается от варианта `List<String>[] lsa = new ArrayList[10]` - точно так же в левой части параметризованный тип, а в правой - raw type. И точно так же должно появиться предупреждение об unchecked assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays)

> You cannot create arrays of parameterized types. For example, the following code does not compile:
>
> `List<Integer>[] arrayOfLists = new List<Integer>[2];`  // compile-time error

Так что придется делать список списков.

---

Можно попробовать сделать так:

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] group = (ArrayList<Integer>[])new ArrayList[4];
```

Но, ИМХО, это костыльно.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что массивы в Java ковариантны (т.е. если класс `B` - наследник `A`, то `B[]` - наследник `A[]` и мутабельны (значение элементов массива можно менять). Т.е. можно написать:

```
String[] strings = new String[1];
Object[] objects = strings; // ковариантность
objects[0] = new Object();  // мутабельность, эта строка компилируется,
                            // но при запуске выдаст исключение.
```

При попытке использовать элемент `strings`, например `strings[0].length()`, произошла бы ошибка, т.к. на самом деле в массиве лежит `Object`. Такие ошибки сложно исправлять, потому что заполнение и использование массива могут находиться в разных частях программы. Поэтому, при присвоении значения элементу, происходит проверка соответствия типа, и может быть [выброшено исключение](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.5) `java.lang.ArrayStoreException`.

Дженерики в java реализованы с помощью type erasure, информация о конкретных значениях параметров типов известна только на этапе компиляции ([non-reifiable types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.7)), а во время выполнения типы `List<String>` и `List<Integer>` "стираются" до простого `List`. Поэтому проверить, что элементу массива `List<String>[]` присваивается именно `List<String>` невозможно, и создание массивов с non-reifiable элементами [запрещено](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10).

Дженерики по-умолчанию инвариантны (`List<String>` не является наследником `List<Object>` и наоборот), поэтому можно использовать коллекции обобщенных типов.